# Как проверить, что переменная != (степень двойки - 1)

Tags: python

Как написать проверку, что число не является (степенью двойки - 1), не прибегая к использованию заранее заполненного списка подобных чисел:

```
f2 = [1,3,7,15]
x = int(input("Задать: "))
if x not in (f2):
    print ("Нет")
else:
    print ("Да")
```

А как-то с помошью вот этого

```
(x != 0) && !(x & (x - 1)
```

или вот этого

```
 while (((x % 2) == 0) && x > 1) /* While x is even and > 1 */
   x /= 2;
 return (x == 1);
```

методов?

Comment: Хм. Сосчитать количество единиц (число-то положительное?). Если одна -- то степень двойки (при x == 1 -- нулевая).

    n = 0
    while x>0:
      n += 1
      x = x & (x - 1)

Comment: А не сложно было бы в контексте задачи это показать? Я наоборот, с недосыпа, не могу прочесть выражение, торможу.

Comment: @pikey, этот метод основан на битовом представлении целых чисел.

Распишите числа, являющиеся степенями двойки в битовом виде (0-ми и 1-чками). Вы обнаружите, что в записи любого из них ровно одна единичка в какой-нибудь позиции. Соответственно, для других это не так (минимум 2 единичных бита).

Поэтому, если от степени двойки отнять 1, то единственная единичка станет 0-м, а нули правее ее станут единичками.

Когда к таким комбинациям битиков мы применим операцию AND (она же `&`), то результат будет нулем.

Что @alexlz и проверяет.

Надеюсь, зачем перед этим проверка числа на ноль -- понятно.

Comment: @pikey

     #!/usr/bin/python2.7
     print [x for x in range(0, 11) if not (x and x & (x - 1) == 0)]
     [0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]

Comment: @alexlz
Не, не совсем то. Но всё равно спасибо, я тут пока читал всё это, понял как надо: 

def po2minus1 ():
    x = int(input("Enter: "))
    f = []
    f = range(2, x)
    for i in (f):
        if (i and i & (i - 1) == 0):
            i = i-1
            print (i)
po2minus1 ()
Enter: 100
3
7
15
31
63

@avp
Ок, спасибо за пояснения. Так гораздо яснее, чем сухим языком мануалов.

Comment: Осталось только сообразить, как все значения (i-1) отправить в список, чтобы потом можно было уже относительно этого списка делать проверку.
PS
тормоз, rtfm и всё такое. Значения заносятся в список так: f2.append(i), предварительно объявив f2 как список.

Comment: @pikey вот что-то я Вас совсем не понимаю. Не могли бы Вы на пальцах объяснить, что же Вам всё-таки надо?

Answer (score 5):

А так не пойдет?

```
from math import log
r = log(a+1)/log(2.)
print r!=int(r)
```

Comment: Пойдёт, если логарифм разложить в ряд, а вычисления производить с рациональными числами.

Comment: @alexlz, а зачем?

Comment: @mikillskegg ну если в операциях над целыми появляются логарифмы, то уж на импорте math останавливаться не стоит.

Comment: @alexlz, так может сразу бинарный модуль забабахать на фортране? Или на Си с ассемблерными вставками.

Comment: @mikillskegg ага, модуль на алголе для ТА-1М с кодовыми вставками.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, буквально на пальцах - нужно было сделать проверку, является ли переменная одним из начений множества ((степень двойки)- 1).

Было поздно, меня беспощадно заклинило, и потому не мог сформулировать.
Однако пока читал этот пост - расклинило. Получилось примерно так:

```
def po2Minus1 ():
    global testvalue
    global limit
    limit = int(input("Enter upper limit: "))
    f = []
    x = range(2, limit)
    for i in (x):
        if (i and i & (i - 1) == 0):
            i = i-1
            f.append(i)
    testvalue = int(input("Enter test value: "))
    if testvalue not in (f):
        print ("The number you entered is not a power of 2 minus 1")
    else:
        print ("The number you entered is a power of 2 minus 1")
```

Вот. За что всем поучаствовавшим спасибо. Наверняка можно то же самое написать компактней, только я не знаю как.

Comment: @pikey, вот только не пойму, зачем нужно *хранить* такое множество?

Достаточно ведь просто проверять, является ли  **`x + 1`** степенью двойки.

Comment: @avp Да, вы правы. Глобальная переменная здесь ни о чём, я её на автомате прописал, на всякий случай, не зная пригодится ли оно в дальнейшем, или нет. Вобще, эта проверка - она часть логической игры, и лимит там в самом начале либо генерируется один раз, случайным образом,  либо жёстко прописывается. Тут я просто сдела ручной ввод, чтобы было удобней тестировать.

Comment: @pikey, про переменную limit, это так, к слову пришлось.

Основная же мысль заключается в том, что **хранить в памяти** множество, элементы которого **легко вычисляются** (то же самое, принадлежность к которому легко проверяется) просто **не нужно**.

Answer (score 2):

У вас уже в самом вопросе приведена проверка того, является ли число степенью двойки. Можно немного её модифицировать и получить то, что требуется. Я использовал подобную схему работы с битами, наверняка её можно улучшить:

```
def check(x):
    return x ^ (x + 1) == 2 * x + 1
```

Она основана на том, что в двоичной системе счисления число, равное степени двойки без единицы, представлено в виде последовательности `n` единиц: `11...111`. Добавив единицу к этому числу мы получим число, в записи которого будет одна единица и `n` нулей: `100...000`.

Для удобства запишу их друг под другом и сложу их побитово по модулю два:

```
  11...111 +
 100...000 =
 111...111
```

Побитовое сложение по модулю два даст в сумме число, равное удвоенному изначальному числу плюс один только в одном случае -- когда были сложены число, равное степени двойки и это же число без единицы. Это довольно несложно понять и доказать.

**UPD**

Добавлю из комментария @VlaD упрощённый вариант:

```
def check(x):
    return not x & (x + 1)
```

Он работает ровно по той же причине, что и код выше.

Comment: Наверняка тогда проще будет `x | (x + 1) == ~0` или `x & (x + 1) == 0`.

Comment: @VladD Первое не работает, так как `x | (x + 1)` в Python даст всегда положительное число, а `~0 == -1`

Comment: @VladD а второе да, проще, спасибо. Немного поправил его и внёс в ответ.

Comment: @VladD Я пробовал преобразовать выражение из условия `!(x & (x - 1))` в выражение на Python, но почему-то думал использовать оператор `~` вместо оператора `not`.

Comment: `check()` не очень информативное имя. Можно использовать [`not_power_two_minus_one()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469115/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный способ [определить является ли целое число степенью двойки](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2):

```
def is_power_two(n):
    assert n >= 0
    return n != 0 and n & (n - 1) == 0
```

Поэтому чтобы узнать, что переменная является *положительной* степенью двойки минус один (`n` -> `n+1`):

```
def is_pos_power_two_minus_one(n):
    assert n >= 0
    return n != 0 and (n + 1) & n == 0
```

Обратное условие:

```
def not_pos_power_two_minus_one(n):
    assert n >= 0
    return n == 0 or (n + 1) & n != 0
```

Пример:

```
for n in range(10):
    not_ = "not " * not_pos_power_two_minus_one(n)
    print("{n} {n:04b} is {not_}(2**N - 1)".format(**vars()))
```

#### Результат

```
0 0000 is not (2**N - 1)
1 0001 is (2**N - 1)
2 0010 is not (2**N - 1)
3 0011 is (2**N - 1)
4 0100 is not (2**N - 1)
5 0101 is not (2**N - 1)
6 0110 is not (2**N - 1)
7 0111 is (2**N - 1)
8 1000 is not (2**N - 1)
9 1001 is not (2**N - 1)
```

Если разрешить `N == 0`, то `2**0 == 1` и поэтому ноль является *"(степень двойки - 1)"*. В итоге *"переменная != (степень двойки - 1)"*:

```
def not_power_two_minus_one(n):
    assert n >= 0
    return (n + 1) & n != 0
```

что совпадает со вторым решением в [ответе @Timofey Bondarev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468985/23044).

#### Объяснение

Cтепень двойки (`2**N`) в двоичном представлении это просто единичка c `N` нулями, например: `2**3 == 0b1000`, соответственно "(степень двойки - 1)" (`2**N - 1`) -- это просто `N` единичек, например: `2**3 - 1 == 0b0111`. Очевидно, что `2**N & (2**N - 1) == 0` (где `N >= 0`), например:

```
    1000
&   0111
    ----
    0000
```

потому что `0 & 1 == 0`, где `&` это побитовое "и". То есть, если `n` это степень двойки, то `n & (n - 1) == 0`.

Также верно обратное: если `n & (n - 1) == 0` для положительного целого числа `n`, то `n` это степень двойки («от противного» можно доказать).

Таким образом, `n & (n - 1) == 0` условие является необходимым и достаточным для положительных целых чисел, чтобы определить, что `n` -- это степень двойки (`2**N`).